# Reference/book recommendations for search data structure

Tags: data-structures, reference-request, searching

I am interested in data structures that support efficient searching of various kinds.

When I read the Wikipedia page of "search data structure", it says "Useful search data structures allow faster retrieval; however, they are limited to queries of some specific kind". So, obviously, there exists a correlation of one specific data structure and the searching operations it supports. For example, k-d tree supports efficient query of multiple-dimensional data.

Of course, the data structures I am thinking about are not limited to arrays or trees. They can also be graphs or more advanced structures.

I am new to this field. So I am wondering if anyone can recommend some books or review papers that summarize different search/query data structures.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Each data structure has its own pro's as well as con's . If you provide more specific information that would be better like where you want to use it etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree that each data structure has its own pros and cons. That's why each data structure is designed for supporting one or more queries efficiently. I am looking for a review or summary of " what data structure supports what queries".

Comment: We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a [general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems explained there. If you are not sure how to improve your question maybe we can help you in [chat]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly recommend MIT course on Advanced Data Structures, I was watching  Eric Demaines lectures, he shows multiple examples, here are some of them:

- [Van Emde Boas tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Emde_Boas_tree)
- [Y-fast trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-fast_trie)

Here some suggested reading from their [website](https://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.851/fall17/):

- [Data Structures and Network Algorithms by Robert E. Tarjan (covers
  BSTs, splay trees, link-cut trees)](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611970265)
- [Open Data Structures by Pat Morin (covers BSTs, B-trees, hashing, and
  some integer data structures)](http://opendatastructures.org/)

[MIT course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-851-advanced-data-structures-spring-2012/)

[YouTube lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0yzrZL1py0)